# academic word for holding a ceremony

Tags: synonyms, latin, academia

How to say it in academic way to hold a ceremony/wedding/workshop?

I am looking for an academic (Latin-based) word for `hold` in this context.

`Arrange` is a good word but it does not give the same sense.

Comment: **conduct** -- the department of humanities *conducted* an academic workshop on modern trends in the arts and the social sciences. *The wedding was conducted soberly, with festivities kept to a minimum.*

Comment: @EnglishStudent thank you very much. Are there other possible variations?

Comment: querr, you can probably get more support for your question if you provide an example sentence or two, showing how you'd like to use the word. // @EnglishStudent - *conduct* is good, how about an answer? // *Celebrate* might also work, depending on the context.

Comment: @aparente001 thank you - now posted 'conduct' as an answer - please think of other choices for OP!

Comment: Being Latin-based doesn't make a word any more or less appropriate for academic use, at least among any members of academia who belong there.

Answer (score 2):

A good choice would be **conduct**

> **conduct** [*transitive verb*]  2b :  to direct or take part in the operation or management of
>
> conduct an experiment
>
> conduct a business
>
> conduct an investigation

[Definition of **conduct** at Merriam-Webster dictionary online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conduct)

Examples:

> The department of humanities **conducted** an academic workshop on modern trends in the liberal arts and the social sciences.
>
> The wedding ***was conducted*** soberly, with festivities kept to a minimum.
>
> When could you find the time **to conduct** this ceremony?